# How to find provisioning profile's name by target name or bundle identifier it's associated with?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

We have (figuratively speaking) a ton of Provisioning Profiles (PPs) because of a large number of non- production environments in addition to a widget, a watch app and a tv app. Given that we do not have a good PP naming convention, is there a way to find a correct PP's **name** knowing the `target` name or the `bundle identifier`? When there's a trouble with a PP during `XCode` build, I basically want to copy something to clipboard and be able to `Command-F` the `Developer Portal` PP page to find the culprit provisioning profile.

PS. We are changing our PP naming convention going forward but meanwhile we still have to manage PPs that already exist.

Comment: Do you need to have explicit bundle IDs / provisioning profiles?  If it's all for one company, and there are no security resons to have individual bundle IDs / profiles, you could use a wildcard app ID and a single provisioning profile.  That would make management a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tab in the Developer Portal, under `Identifiers`, called `App Id's`. It's a list of all bundle id's and their respective names.